# Programmatically disabling webform component - Drupal 7

Tags: webforms, forms

According to [hook_form_alter doc for webform](https://drupal.org/node/1558246), I can target the component's properties using $form['submitted']['component_name'], etc. This works fine for altering title, weight, description. The form structure of webform looks something like:

```
Array
(
  [#tree] => 1
  [component_email] => Array
     (
       [#type] => webform_email
       [#title] => Email
         .
         .
       [#webform_component] => Array
         (
           .
           .
           [extra] => Array
             .
             [disabled] => 0
```

Simply changing the disabled property to `true` or `1` doesn't disabled the component. I have also tried the $form['#node']->webform path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never had luck trying to set the disabled flag via a FormsAPI hook using the array indexes.  Looking at the code above, it would also seem that you are setting the incorrect 'disabled' for the form array - [#disabled](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#disabled) is what is checked during the rendering process.

But, like I said, never had much luck with it anyway.  What you may end up needing to do is set the #attributes array for the form element, specifically identifying the disabled property as in the html element tag:

```
<input type='text' disabled />
// becomes
$form['element']['#attributes'] = array('disabled' => '1');
```

obviously with the form indexes specified as needed.

Comment: Thank you sir!
`$form['submitted']['component_name']['#attributes']['disabled'] = true` did the trick